# Combining JOIN, GROUP BY, and HAVING SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, having

```
SELECT works_with.client_id AS 'Client ID',
    client.client_name AS 'Client Name',
    works_with.total_sales AS 'Total Sales'
FROM works_with
JOIN client
ON works_with.client_id = client.client_id
GROUP BY works_with.client_id
HAVING SUM(works_with.total_sales);
```

client:

| client_id | client_name | branch_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | Dunmore Highschool | 2 |
| 401 | Lackawana Country | 2 |
| 402 | FedEx | 3 |
| 403 | John Daly Law, LLC | 3 |
| 404 | Scranton Whitepages | 2 |
| 405 | Times Newspaper | 3 |
| 406 | FedEx2 | 2 |

works_with:

| emp_id | client_id | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 401 | 267000 |
| 102 | 406 | **15000** |
| 105 | 400 | 55000 |
| 105 | 404 | 33000 |
| 105 | 406 | **130000** |
| 107 | 403 | **5000** |
| 107 | 405 | 26000 |
| 108 | 402 | 22500 |
| 108 | 403 | **12000** |

My goal is to join client.client_id, client.client_name, and works_with.total_sales. Additionally, I would like to eliminate duplicate clients while maintaining their total_sales numbers:

| client_id | client_name | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | Dunmore Highschool | 55000 |
| 401 | Lackawana Country | 267000 |
| 402 | FedEx | 22500 |
| 403 | John Daly Law, LLC | **17000** |
| 404 | Scranton Whitepages | 33000 |
| 405 | Times Newspaper | 26000 |
| 406 | FedEx2 | **145000** |

But what I get is:

| client_id | client_name | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | Dunmore Highschool | 55000 |
| 401 | Lackawana Country | 267000 |
| 402 | FedEx | 22500 |
| 403 | John Daly Law, LLC | **5000** |
| 404 | Scranton Whitepages | 33000 |
| 405 | Times Newspaper | 26000 |
| 406 | FedEx2 | **15000** |

It groups by client_id but doesn't ADD.

Comment: It's not helpful to just say you (re)searched. Re (re)search: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: HAVING takes a predicate. SUM is a value. Your HAVING SUM(...) interprets the sum as a boolean. PS (As can be expected,) When pinned down, your questions will be faqs. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
works_with.client_id AS 'Client ID',
client.client_name AS 'Client Name',
SUM(works_with.total_sales) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM works_with
JOIN client ON works_with.client_id = client.client_id
GROUP BY works_with.client_id;
```

The GROUP BY will ensure that you only get 1 record of each client with the total sales summed for each client id.

Comment: @Ryan Please ask a new (researched non-duplicate) question in a new post, not in comments.